# Difference between verb ~ている + (瞬間・とき)

Tags: syntax

I know that verb + ~ている+ 瞬間【しゅんかん】　has a similar usage to ~ている+とき,  for example 目を閉じている瞬間 and 目を閉じているとき.

I want to know what is the difference between these two in general, will it change the meaning of the sentence if I use しゅんかん　over とき？

Comment: I edited the question and turned the part about +うえ into a side-question for now. Is this supposed to be a side question? Or are you uncertain when to use うえ vs. とき or しゅんかん? If it is not a side question, feel free to edit the question or leave a comment. If it is a side question, I think it would be better to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Yup it was supposed to be a side question but I was hoping for an answer that would tell me the difference between these three patterns.

Comment: Sorry I need to ask again, but verb+うえ is a bit different in meaning compated to しゅんかん and とき. If you don't know the difference between うえ and the other two, that's fine and then it's not a side question ;)

Comment: Yeah , I don't really know the pattern っている+うえ, I just had the feeling that it is somehow related to ってる＋とき.

Comment: @Johji If you're asking about the time-based relation, it's not clear without a complete sentence. As is, I think it would be more clearly temporally related if it were うえで, because I took those examples to mean "in addition to; on top of...".

Comment: I think the difference between "～する瞬間" (the moment ～) and "～する時" (when ～) is obvious, as long as you know what 瞬間 is. Are you specifically asking about "～している瞬間", the combination of the *progressive form* and 瞬間?

Comment: They are the same. To my hear, 瞬間 sounds shorter. This is a small nuance but i would say : している時~'at the moment', している瞬間~'at the exact moment' or something like that

Comment: @WKx Thanks, the difference seems to be not so obvious even when they know 瞬間 means moment.

Comment: As you've accepted the answer, I've gone ahead and removed the side question. Please feel free to ask it as a new question. You can [view the edit history here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/23519/revisions) if you want to copy&paste the side question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japanese 瞬間 always refers to a *very* short period of time, typically less than a second. (It can refer to a longer period of time, for example if you're talking about the history of the earth, though.)

- 目を閉じる瞬間 the very moment someone closes their eyes
- 目を閉じている時 when someone's eyes are closed

So you cannot use 瞬間 in the following sentence:

> 眠るために目を閉じている時、眼球は素早く運動することがあり、これを[レム睡眠](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_eye_movement_sleep)と呼ぶ。

目を閉じ**ている**瞬間 is an expression we would seldom encounter. In general, the progressive form `～ている` implies the situation persists over a longer period of time, and thus it doesn't go very well with 瞬間.

Only when you know the eyes will be closed for a very short period of time, you can say something like this:

> [まばたき](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink)のために目を閉じている瞬間を、ふだん人間は認識していない。

(I'm sorry, but your "side question" is totally irrelevant to the main question. Could you ask it separately?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , I am confused myself in the first place. I just had this feeling that [verb+うえ＋で] is somehow related to time.